# Why does my use of Perl's split function not split?

Tags: html, perl, split

I'm trying to split an HTML document into its head and body:

```
my @contentsArray = split( /<\/head>/is, $fileContents, 1);
if( scalar @contentsArray == 2 ){
    $bodyContents = $dbh->quote(trim($contentsArray[1]));
    $headContents = $dbh->quote(trim($contentsArray[0]) . "</head>"); 
}
```

is what i have. `$fileContents` contains the HTML code. When I run this, it doesn't split. Any one know why?

Comment: Using just a text string to parse an HTML doc is a bad idea in anything but the most artificial circumstances.  You really should consider using a module like HTML::Parser.

Comment: Voting to close as "no longer relevant". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216274/why-does-my-use-of-perls-split-function-not-split/2216304#2216304

Comment: @Sinan Ünür: it's still a good question, that seems to me to be more likely than most to help some later searcher.

Comment: Link stated previously, I cannot use the parser as the file may contain a server side language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry, figured it out. Thought the 1 was how many times it would find the expression not limit the results. Changed to 2 and works.

Comment: Don't post non-answers. Update your question or use comments instead.

Comment: @Sinan Ünür: looks like an answer to me.  I only bothered to post a separate answer because "limit the results" could be interpreted wrongly.

Answer (score 6):

The third parameter to split is how many results to produce, so if you want to apply the expression only once, you would pass 2.

Note that this does actually limit the number of times the pattern is used to split the string (to one fewer than the number passed), not just limit the number of results returned, so this:

```
print join ":", split /,/, "a,b,c", 2;
```

outputs:

```
a:b,c
```

not:

```
a:b
```